Pen and notebook carrying in Judaism
Is it a Jewish custom for a Jewish person to carry a pen and a notebook in the pocket of their long-sleeved shirt?

No, nothing specifically Jewish about this

In some third world countries, this signifies that the wearer can read and write.
